# changing column name in html table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a html table as below

```
 <table id="searchResults" class="compact-table" width="100%">
 <thead>
    <th><label id="Revenue"></label></th>
    <th></th>
 </thead>
```

I am naming the column headers as shown in the code but I want those column names to assign dynamically

I have placed a label named **Revenue**
for that label I am assigning value using **Jquery** as below

```
var yearVal = $("#salesDashboardYearDropDown").val();
var monthVal = $('select#salesDashboardMonthDropDown :selected').text();
var revenueLastYear = (monthVal + ' ' + (yearVal - 1).toString()).toString();
$('#Revenue').html(revenueLastYear);
```

but it is not getting displayed`enter code here`

Comment: it is a drop down there is no problem withj that I am getting the required value into revenue last year variable but i am unable to assign it to label

Comment: Can you just provide it anyway or give us a jsFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: Maybe you have more than one element with `id="Revenue"`?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have used `id` in your select`elements like`salesDashboardMonthDropDown
`and`salesDashboardMonthDropDown` with **no spacces**

I have tried this and it works,

```
$(function(){
    $("#salesDashboardYearDropDown, #salesDashboardMonthDropDown").on('change',function(){
        var yearVal = $("#salesDashboardYearDropDown").val();
        var monthVal = $('#salesDashboardMonthDropDown  :selected').text();
        var revenueLastYear = (monthVal + ' ' + (yearVal - 1).toString()).toString();
        $('#Revenue').html(revenueLastYear);
    });
});
```

Also check you have added any version of `jquery`

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZmuSL/